# Addressability of dojo widget inside of a custom widget

Tags: dojo, widget, custom-widgets, dojo-1.8

I think I'm missing something obvious here in Dojo 1.8 w.r.t. writing custom widgets.

I have a simple widget that includes, among other things, a currencyTextBox.

At runtime, I would like to be able to change the currency of that widget to USD or EUR or whatever else.

Normally, if this **wasn't** a widget, I could do that simply with

registry.byId("myCurrentTextBox").set("currency","USD");

But nested widgets inside of custom widgets don't get registered in the registry.   So, what's the trick to getting addressability to the widget and assigning **widget** attributes (not just **DOM** attributes) for a widget nested inside a custom widget?

Answer (score 0):

Add `data-dojo-attach-point="myCurrentTextBox"` to the widget definition in the template.  Then from within the widget you can access the textbox using `this.myCurrentTextBox`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, all widgets are added to the registry.
Maybe the id is wrong? I guess by 'registry' it mean you required 'dijit/registry' ?
Did you try with registry.byNode?